# How can I pass parameters into stored procedure programmatically?

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have a report in which I want to pass the parameters using a stored procedure. Now I have certain variables in which the value is static. I want to pass those values as the parameters into the Telerik report. e.g I have a `DropDownList` in which I have three values `Sales` `Person`, `Customer` and `Product`. Now I want to pass the selected index as a parameter to the telerik report designer. As I am new to this I do not know that what values I should pass in the designer and what values I have to pass pro-grammatically. I have designed the report but when set the value of parameter = new Report Parameter it gives me error that `object reference not set to the instance if the object`. Can anyone please help me.

I am using Telerik report designer inside the visual studio and Telerik report viewer for displaying the report.

http://blogs.telerik.com/telerikreportingteam/posts/09-03-14/telerik-reporting-connecting-to-stored-procedures.aspx
I have followed this link but it is OBSOLETE now.

http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/how-to-sqldatasource-sct-storedprocedure.html
and while following the other link I get confused at the 10th point.

Comment: You might want to include any applicable code you have written. From what you've written I am guessing the exception is being thrown because the Report hasn't been created when you start trying to add parameters.

Comment: When you run the report from the design view does it execute ok?